# Re-Request POST data python on same page

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can login to a domain successfully, and extract a page, which contain a message(which is randomly generated on each(GET/POST request), and a form, my task is to manipulate the message(string) on the page and submit to the same page. Below is the code I am trying.

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://login_page/login'
    USERNAME = 'my_username'
    PASSWORD = 'my_password'

    login_data = dict(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
    s.post(url, data=login_data, headers={
        'Referer': 'https://login_page'})
```

The above code successfully logs me to the website.
The next request is to the page where I need to read the content that is,

```
r = s.get('https://page_which_creates_random_message')
"""
code to manipulate the string, and answer is stored in a varible, lets say 
result = 'Answer/manipulated_string'
"""
```

if i try to submit the result, that is,

```
sub_string = {'submitbutton' : result}
s.post('https:/page_which_reates_random_message', data=sub_string)
```

my answer is going to be wrong, because, the s.post which again generate the random message, but the variable result contains the old message answer.
my question is how to submit the sub_string on the same post request with manipulating(calculating) the answer without making another request.

Thanks.

Comment: This really isn't clear, I'm afraid. You're doing exactly the same thing that a user would do in the browser: get the page, then post back a result. So I don't understand the difficulty.

Comment: The s.post request is generating another message/string, which need tobe manipulate.